# How do I interface STM32 with the Adafruit BLE SPI Friend module?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, adafruit

I am having trouble getting the Adafruit Bluefruit LE SPI Friend to work with my STM32 NUCLEO-U5A5ZJ-Q. How do I communicate with this module?

I tried looking online for resource that might help, but there are very few/almost none discussing any simple project/example on getting the adafruit bluefruit SPI friend to work with my stm32 nucleo board. or any that use the STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: You simply connect the [Bluetooth module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2633) to the STM board via SPI interfaces, as the module name suggests. However, this sounds more like a hardware question and is therefore more appropriate for this community: [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why you found so little is because this is just another SPI device, which you control like you would control any other SPI device. You need to send some commands over SPI, receive some data from the device. Specifics are in the slave device's datasheet (specific commands and SPI configuration).

Comment: They use something called SDEP, but they have byte limits...